# How to use angular js constants values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I want to remove all hard codings in angular controller, For that I want to load all hot codings from another js file, For Example

```
modalHeader = "Success";
```

Here Success is a Hot coding. So I want to load this success from out side js file. In Js controller I want to give key of the success,instead of `"Success"`, I reffered many articals But there is no useful for this scenario.Please give some info to proceed like this,as I am fresher to angularJS

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see my answer @ShivaGoudA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use constants for this . Constant values can be accessed all over the  application . You just inject the constant into controller or service to use.

Define constants or values

```
var app = angular
  .module('test');

app.constant("ENV", {
  "CON1": "val1",
  "CON2": "val2",
  "CON3: "val3",
});
```

And use in service

```
angular.module('test')
  .service('testService', function ($http, ENV)
```

or in controller

```
 angular.module('test')
  .controller('testController ', function ($http, ENV)
```

values are accessible via `ENV.CON1`

Comment: what is the extention for the constant file

Comment: simple js file liek any other js you can use it .. mark as accepted if this helps :) @ShivaGoudA

Comment: I am getting ENV dependency problem BOSS

Comment: you missed something.. post another question with that